# Using native modules like Google Maps in a React Native app and Expo

Tags: react-native

Relatively new to React Native, I’m using AirBnb’s react native maps package in my app, and all the tutorials talk about getting Google Maps (rather than Apple Maps) to work in iOS by going into my iOS folder and managing the cocoapods dependencies etc.

I don’t completely remember, but I created my app with expo init, or maybe with create-react-native-app, and I don’t have an iOS folder. From what I’ve read it looks like I can get the separate folders by ejecting my app.

Here is what my actual question is about: The question is basically “Can I use Google Maps in an iOS MapView and still code my app in React Native and run it in Expo in both Xcode simulator and Android emulator, and still have hot/live loading?”

You could abstract the question just a bit and phrase it as “Can I follow the instructions on, say, a MapView tutorial, to use native dependencies, having iOS and Android folders, and still write my app in React Native and run it in both simulators with hot/live loading?”

(Or, once I’m using the native stuff do I have to code in Swift/Java and Xcode/Android Studio?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the expo documentation, expo already contains a google maps map view.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/ 

 if you didn't create your app with expo but just with the `create-react-native-app` command you can use this package maintained by the RN community:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps

This package uses native components so you need to link it (only if you don't use expo) and then you can just use it in your screens as a normal component.

Comment: Thanks Rik, I'll look into that expo component right away. Can you say more about your last sentence, including what to do if I /do/ use expo? Is expo the only way to have hot/live reloading?

Comment: No, you'll also have hot reloading in a create-react-native-app. When you use expo you get a lot of packages that you'll probably use in your app pre-included. Like the map, imagepicker etc. Expo also makes it easier to share your prototype app with co-workers or test it on your phone easier. Hope this cleared it up for you.

Comment: Well I'm not talking about building with `expo init` I'm talking about running an app from somewhere other than Expo. I haven't actually done this before; I imagine you open the project in Xcode and run from there (does this require ejecting? this goes back to the "actual" question of my original post). Does it hot-reload when running this way?

Comment: As far as I know that's not the right way to run your react native app (I could be wrong I'm also pretty new to RN). i just run my app by running the command `react-native run-ios` (or Android depending on the os you want to use). If you don't have the ios or Android folder in your project then you need to run the eject command, this will create the folders for you.make sure to build your app via xcode before running `react-native run-ios`, if you skip that you might encounter some problems.

Comment: So when you eject to run `run-ios`, do you keep working on the RN/JS code?

Comment: Correct. There can be moments when you need to work in xcode etc. but that's only if you want to make your own native components (like the map that has already been built)